A test to show that one list is greater than another
I have calculated cancer stemness scores (NES) for each cell in different cell types. When visualized, I can see that the peak of malignant cells has greater NES than the peak of heapocytes.

I ran Welch Two Sample t-test on R to see if the mean of one is greater than another's but got p-value=1. Is there any other way to compare those two lists so it captures the difference?

Can you elaborate on the context? (what is the research question you're trying to answer, why did you choose a t-test in the first place, will you make comparisons between other groups? etc.). Note that this is not a good practice to try multiple tests just to find one that will give you a p-value you're happy with, in particular if you intend to not report all the tests you conducted.

There is a bug somewhere. $p=1$ is almost impossible, unless the 2 datasets are virtually identical; based on the graph they are clear not (similar variance, but shifted mean). Now, you may get a high p, but not 1... Now one way my students often get this issue, is by running a single sided test (you may; after all you were trying to show malignants>hapatocytes), but running it with the wrong direction. Try the test again, but reversing the alternative; you will get a very low p-value.

yes, I ran it in the wrong direction. Thank you for your comment. @jginestet
Is it a good test to tell that the scores in malignant cells are higher than in hepatocytes?

@Glen_b, she said she ran a Welch t-test...

@YuliaKentieva, it is a very fine test if you are interested in finding differences in the average NES score. It depends on the research question you are trying to answer.

@jginestet yes, that's definitely what it says. I don't know how I managed to misread that. Deleting previous comment
